# How to retrieve variables defined in a particular include file in php?

Tags: php, include

I want to know all the variables that have been declared within an include file.

Example code is:

1. Include file:

   ```
   <?php
   $a = 1;
   $b = 2;
   $c = 3;
   $myArr = array(5,6,7);
   ?>
   ```
2. Main file:

   ```
   <?php

   $first = get_defined_vars();
   include_once("include_vars.php");
   $second = get_defined_vars();

   $diff = array_diff($second ,$first);
   var_dump($diff);

   $x = 12;
   $y = 13;
   ?>
   ```

My attempt to use difference of get_defined_vars() does not seem to give accurate information.
It gives:

```
array(2) {
  ["b"]=>
  int(2)
  ["c"]=>
  int(3)
}
```

$a and $myArr seem to be missing.
What are other methods I can use?

Comment: Don't use global variables.  Let me repeat that.  Don't use global variables.  Pass around variables wrapped in containers such as an object. Note that I said pass around, not call globally. Read about [Dependency Injection](http://www.phparch.com/2010/03/static-methods-vs-singletons-choose-neither/)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really not a good thing to do this, hope it's needed just for debugging. Then you should find a difference between keys of the arrays that `get_defined_vars` return, not between their values:

```
$diff = array_diff(array_keys($second),array_keys($first));
```

If you don't want to include your file, a more complicated way would be using [`Tokenizer`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tokenizer.php):

```
$tokens = token_get_all(file_get_contents("include_vars.php")); 

foreach($tokens as $token) {
    if ($token[0] == T_VARIABLE)
        echo $token[1] . ', ';
}
```

That would return all variables, even non-globals ones and the ones that were unset in that script (!)

Comment: Yes it is needed just for debugging purpose. Not a part of core implementation.

Comment: I would also appreciate if you can suggest other methods too.

Comment: Finding difference between those arrays is the best method. Added about Tokenizer, but I wouldn't use it